# When should I use Spring @Bean and use @Autowired in it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to understand exactly in which cases I should create a spring @Bean method which will return a new instance of a class. and I will @autowired that @Bean method in other classes to use it. I know this is at the very basic of spring but I don't seems to get hold on to it. Here are some code sample to clarify my need in more details. I understand the basic theory behind it but want to get in more depth knowledge.

```
@Component

public class instanceConfig {
        
        @Bean
        public RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest() {
                return new RunInstancesRequest();
        }
}
```

```
@Component
public class someClsss {
        
        @Autowired
        private RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest; 

        //do some work using the runInstancesRequest
}
```

Comment: Your `InstanceConfig` class should be annotated with `@Configuration` (and the class name should start with an uppercase `I`).

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer this question, because this question has troubled me for a long time.

First, let's agree on:

1. I'm your housekeeper, my name is spring;
2. You like to eat beans, but you neither grow beans nor distinguish beans by shape;
3. The buyer will go to buy various kinds of beans, put the bags of beans into boxes, and put labels on the bags of various beans;
4. Whenever you want a certain bean, you can always ask me for it;
5. There are several packages of special beans, which are breakfast beans, lunch beans, and dinner beans;
6. As a housekeeper, I will make your breakfast nutritionally balanced (put in a variety of beans).

Then, let's look at the code:

```
package com;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class Index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The housekeeper got a box of beans. 
        // At the same time, he needs to manage a breakfast of beans
        ApplicationContext housekeeper = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanBox.class, BreakfastBeans.class);
        
        // If you want breakfast, just ask the butler for breakfast beans
        BreakfastBeans breakfast = housekeeper.getBean("breakfastBeans", BreakfastBeans.class);
        breakfast.eat();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("It's ten o'clock in the morning, I've worked for two hours, I'm in a bad mood, I want to eat sweet red beans");
        // If you want red beans, ask the butler directly for red beans
        EdibleBeans wantToEatRedBeans = housekeeper.getBean("redBean", EdibleBeans.class);
        wantToEatRedBeans.eat();
    }
}

// This is a box of beans I bought back. @Configuration tell the housekeeper that he need to manage these beans according to the labels inside
@Configuration
class BeanBox {
    // label the coffee beans
    @Bean(name="coffeeBean")
    public EdibleBeans oh_thisIsCoffeeBeans() { return new CoffeeBeans(); }

    // label the kidney beans
    @Bean(name="kidneyBean")
    public EdibleBeans oh_thisIsKidneyBeans() { return new KidneyBeans(); }

    // label the red beans
    @Bean(name="redBean")
    public EdibleBeans oh_thisIsRedBeans() { return new RedBeans(); }

    // label the green beans
    @Bean(name="greenBean")
    public EdibleBeans oh_thisIsGreenBeans() { return new GreenBeans(); }
}

// Mark a special class of beans
@Component
class BreakfastBeans {
    // I am a housekeeper. 
    // I think there should be some coffee beans and kidney beans for breakfast. 
    // I want to see if there are such beans in the beans I manage. 
    // If there are, then put them directly in the breakfast bean category
    @Autowired
    private EdibleBeans coffeeBean;
    @Autowired
    private EdibleBeans kidneyBean;

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("breakfast time:");
        coffeeBean.eat();
        kidneyBean.eat();
    }
}

interface EdibleBeans {
    public void eat();
}

class CoffeeBeans implements EdibleBeans {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("\tEat Coffee Beans");
    }
}
class KidneyBeans implements EdibleBeans {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("\tEat Kidney Beans");
    }
}
class RedBeans implements EdibleBeans {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("\tEat Red Beans");
    }
}
class GreenBeans implements EdibleBeans {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("\tEat Green Beans");
    }
}
```

The result of code execution is:

```
breakfast time:
    Eat Coffee Beans
    Eat Kidney Beans
It's ten o'clock in the morning, I've worked for two hours, I'm in a bad mood, I want to eat sweet red beans
    Eat Red Beans
```

See, you don't need to manage any beans yourself, you just tell the housekeeper what beans you want and you will get it.

Comment: Very friendly and understandable example.

Answer (score 2):

When we annotate a method with `@Bean`, it tells Spring to instantiate and configure an object of that class as a bean. We typically use `@Bean` in a configuration class (annotated with `@Configuration`) to define beans that are managed by Spring's container. It gives us fine-grained control over the instantiation and configuration of beans.

```
    @Component
    public class instanceConfig {
            
            @Bean
            public RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest() {
                    return new RunInstancesRequest();
            }
    }
```

`@Autowired` annotation is used for automatic dependency injection. When we  annotate a field, constructor, or setter method with `@Autowired`, Spring will automatically wire (inject) the dependencies at runtime. Spring looks for a bean of the required type and injects it into the annotated field or method parameter. It enables us to achieve loose coupling and promotes easier testing and maintainability.

Relationship between `@Bean` and `@Autowired`

[image]

If you donot declare a method with @Bean and try to inject it in some class using @Autowired, then spring will not be able to find the instance of that particular class to be injected in spring container and could give errors like:

- **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:** This exception is thrown when Spring
  cannot find a bean of the required type. It usually occurs if you
  haven't defined the bean using @Bean or if there is a typo in the
  bean name.
- **BeanCreationException:** This exception is a general exception that can
  occur for various reasons, including missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Spring **@Bean** method which will return a new instance of a class in the following cases:

- When you need to create a bean that is state-full, meaning that it has its own internal state that is not shared with other beans. For example, a bean that holds a connection to a database or a file.
- When you need to create a bean that is dependent on other beans, and you want to control the order in which the beans are created. For example, you might have a bean that depends on a database connection, and you want to make sure that the database connection is created before the bean that depends on it.
- When you want to create a bean that is not a singleton, meaning that there can be multiple instances of the bean in the Spring container. This is useful for beans that are expensive to create, or for beans that need to be customized for each request.

In your example, the RunInstancesRequest bean is state-full, because it has its own internal state (the list of instances to create). It is also dependent on other beans, because it needs a database connection to create the instances. Finally, it is not a singleton, because there can be multiple requests to create instances at the same time.

The someClass bean uses the **@Autowired** annotation to inject the RunInstancesRequest bean into its own instance. This allows the someClass bean to use the RunInstancesRequest bean to create instances.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `@Bean` is used to define application level configurations which can be used by other components when needed. For example, if I am using ***Kafka*** in my project, I will be using `@Bean` annotation to define its configurations.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> kafkaConfigs() {

     Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            JsonSerializer.class);
    return config;
  }
```

Now, you can autowire this Bean inside any class that needs the ***Kafka*** configuration.

Note that `@Bean` is defined inside the `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 0):

`@Bean` is a method-level annotation that is used to declare a bean and register with the spring container.

In simple terms, `@Bean` annotation will tell to the Spring container here is my instance of the class, Keep hold and give it back when I asked.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

      @Bean
      public MultiplierService multiplier() {
          return new MultiplierService(2);
      }

}
```

In this example, MultiplierService is a class that provides some service that other components might use. The multiplier() method is annotated with @Bean, which tells Spring to treat it as a bean. When the Spring container starts up, it will call this method to create a new instance of MultiplierService. This instance will be managed by Spring and can be injected into other components that depend on it.

**Please note that `@Bean` annotation is used within a `@Configuration` class, Which is a special type of Spring component that defines the configuration for the application.**

You have created `@Bean` inside the Spring Container. Now problem arises **How to use that Bean?**

Now `@Autowiring` come to a place,

Here is the example of autowiring the **MultiplerService** into the AppService class

```
@Service
public class AppService {

       private final MultiplierService multiplierService;

       public AppService(@Autowired MultiplierService multiplierService) {
             this.multiplierService = multiplierService;
       }

       public int calculate(int aValue) {
             return multiplierService.multiply(aValue);
       }

}
```

**Conclusion:**

`@Bean` is an object that is managed by Spring Framework and it can be used to provide services or functionality to other parts of the application. Also `@Beans` should be under `@Configuration` which treated as a **source of bean definition**

`@Autowired` is an annotation used in Spring Boot to enable automatic dependency injection. It allows the Spring container to provide an instance of a required dependency when a bean is created. This annotation can be used on fields, constructors, and methods to have Spring provide the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just Imagine you want to create spring managed instance of a class whose source code you don't have in your project but you are using it from some library in your project class path. In this case you can't use `@Component` or `@Configuration` because you don't have the source code of that class. You can use `@Bean` annotation to create the spring managed instance of that class e.g. datasource, Kafka etc.

`@Autowired` annotation is used only to create a relationship among these spring managed objects.

So if you have created an instance on your own like using a `new` operator. In this case spring is not responsible to manage it hence you can't autowire it.